# How to engineer a compile-time constant 3-way error code map between numeric codes, string identifiers and string messages?

Tags: typescript, enums

When designing a library, there is a often a need to define an immutable mapping between numeric error codes, error code string mnemonics, and error messages.

What is the BestPractice™ for implementing this data structure in TypeScript while utilizing as much built-in, compile-time constness/immutability as possible? I've been trying to sculpt this with enums, but I am running into quirks upon quirks upon quirks with how enums interact with the TS type system. After a dozen attempts that failed to compile, I will just ask these general questions:

Am I reinventing the wheel? Has this problem been solved? Is there an established, proven technique for doing this?

Comment: Using TypeScript enums for anything other than the most basic stuff is a terrible idea. I would just go for a dictionary with error codes as keys.